# Where can I find the shoes in Evil Nun?

Tags: evil-nun

I was playing Evil Nun recently, and I can't find them anywhere. Can someone please tell me where they are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I played I found them near the locker with all the stickers that say 'eagle' on them, across the hall in one of the little lockers - one of the halls near the gym. I'm pretty sure they are in randomly generated locations though, so not too sure.

Comment: no problem, hope it helped :p